# WebView - JavascriptInterface

Tags: android

i'm using component navigation.  In the application, I have WebView which, if a successful transaction, returns success in javascript, and if unsuccessful it returns unsuccess.  Now I use @JavacscriptInterface here.  My question is whether and how I can use Navigation.findNavController, for example if it is a success to open a fragment, if it is unsuccessful to open another fragment.  I have a problem with how to get View In class where is @JavascriptInterface

Comment: Could you post some snippet of your code?

Comment: Override webView onPageFinished there you can do in the event success, and you can maybe create some sort of timer if the page does not load in eg 5 seconds, you trigger some event timeout and open the fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to create @JavascriptInterface method and for success and unsuccess. also you need to add this interface in webview :

Add interface:

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new YourInterfaceClass(), "webinterface");

public class YourInterfaceClass{
    public YourInterfaceClass() {

    }

    @JavascriptInterface 
    public void success () {
    //do here
    }

    @JavascriptInterface 
    public void unsuccess() {
    //do here

    }
}
```

and call in your webpage like this : webinterface.success()  or webinterface.unsuccess()

Comment: Thanks, thats IT!!